# creating ternary plots in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that is arranged like the following. This is an example from a dataset with 100s of loci.

```
loci      head(%)     tail(%)     wing(%) 
1         20          40          40
2         10          50          40
3         12          48          40
4         22          38          40
```

I wish to make a ternary plot for these, with head, tail, and wing making the three points of the triangle. The edges of the triangle would represent the percentages. How can I begin to do this using pandas? Any guidance would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using matplotlib and a couple functions from the [radar_chart example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html), we can create a radar chart directly from a dataframe.

Before we read the dataframe, you'll want to copy the imports, `radar_factory` and `unit_poly_verts` functions from the example matplotlib provides. You also need `pandas`, obviously.

Your imports will look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Since you want only the `head`, `tail` and `wing`, and it looks like `loci` is an index, I imported the data set with `user_col="loci"`. This means the dataframe looks like this upon import:

```
      head(%)  tail(%)  wing(%)
loci
1          20       40       40
2          10       50       40
3          12       48       40
4          22       38       40
```

Finally, you want to create a function that operates similarly to the code in the example, but instead reads the dataframe. The code below should do that and is based on the code in the `'__main__'` block. I stripped out some of the code that isn't required for this example and unhardcoded the colors:

```
def nColors(k=2, cmap='spectral'):
    if type(cmap) == str:
        cm = plt.get_cmap(cmap)
        colors = [cm(1.*i/(k-1)) for i in range(k)]
    elif cmap==None:
        colors = ['k']
    else:
        colors = cmap
    return colors

def plot_radar(data):
    N = data.shape[1] 
    theta = radar_factory(N, frame='circle')

    spoke_labels = data.columns.tolist()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.25, hspace=0.20, top=0.85, bottom=0.05)

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='radar')

    colors = nColors(len(data), cmap='spectral')

    for i, (index, d) in enumerate(data.iterrows()):
        ax.plot(theta, d.tolist(), color=colors[i])
        ax.fill(theta, d.tolist(), facecolor=colors[i], alpha=0.25)

    ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)
    plt.show()
```

Call this function and pass your dataframe:

```
plot_radar(df)
```

---

This code uses the [spectral](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) color map, but you can change that by passing a valid color map in the `colors = nColors(len(data))` line as the second parameter.

You can either have a circle or a polygon (triangle in this case since there are 3 dimensions).

The above code results in a chart like this:

[image: Circle Plot]

If you change the `frame` parameter in the line `theta = radar_factory(N, frame='circle')` to be `polygon`, you get a chart like this:

[image: Polygon Chart]

Comment: Thanks for this Andy! Can you create scatter ternary plots using matplotlib?

Comment: @Altheman [Yes](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter_demo.html). That example is pretty basic, but it shows it can be done.